# Get component of Date / ISODate in mongo

Tags: datetime, mongodb, mongodb-query, isodate

How to get a component like `minute` from `ISODate` stored in `MongoCollection`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you don't specify a language, I'm going to assume you mean JavaScript, as in the shell.

One of the nice features of the shell is it has tab completion. So you can do something like this:

```
> db.test.insert({x:new Date()});
> var doc = db.test.findOne();
> doc
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4fa131851932655dc45027a9"),
"x" : ISODate("2012-05-02T13:07:17.012Z")
}
> doc.x
ISODate("2012-05-02T13:07:17.012Z")
> doc.x.<TAB><TAB>
doc.x.constructor            doc.x.getSeconds(            doc.x.getUTCMinutes( doc.x.setHours(              doc.x.setUTCHours(           doc.x.toLocaleDateString(
doc.x.getDate(               doc.x.getTime(               doc.x.getUTCMonth(           doc.x.setMilliseconds(       doc.x.setUTCMilliseconds(    doc.x.toLocaleString(
doc.x.getDay(                doc.x.getTimezoneOffset(     doc.x.getUTCSeconds(         doc.x.setMinutes(            doc.x.setUTCMinutes(         doc.x.toLocaleTimeString(
doc.x.getFullYear(           doc.x.getUTCDate(            doc.x.getYear(               doc.x.setMonth(              doc.x.setUTCMonth(           doc.x.toString(
doc.x.getHours(              doc.x.getUTCDay(             doc.x.hasOwnProperty(        doc.x.setSeconds(            doc.x.setUTCSeconds(         doc.x.toTimeString(
doc.x.getMilliseconds(       doc.x.getUTCFullYear(        doc.x.propertyIsEnumerable(  doc.x.setTime(               doc.x.setYear(               doc.x.toUTCString(
doc.x.getMinutes(            doc.x.getUTCHours(           doc.x.setDate(               doc.x.setUTCDate(            doc.x.toDateString(          doc.x.tojson(
doc.x.getMonth(              doc.x.getUTCMilliseconds(    doc.x.setFullYear(           doc.x.setUTCFullYear(        doc.x.toGMTString(           doc.x.valueOf(
```

What you want is probably:

```
> doc.x.getSeconds();
17
> doc.x.getMinutes();
7
> doc.x.getHours();
9
> doc.x.getDate();
2
> doc.x.getMonth();
4
> doc.x.getFullYear();
2012
```

Comment: why ´doc.x.getMonth();´ returns 4 instead of 5.

Comment: Probably because MongoDB uses zero based indexes (starts counting at 0 instead of 1)

Comment: getMonth() is javascript function. It starts from 0. See this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp